# php first word only from mb string

Tags: php, preg-match, preg-split, mbstring

I used preg_match but its returning pdf as it English that's why may be.

But I want to get only 練馬春日町Ⅳ

Is there any way to detect it for mb string.

```
<?php 
// Initialize a sentence to a variable 
$sentence = '練馬春日町Ⅳ　清掃レポート.pdf'; 

// Use preg_match() function to get the 
// first word of a string 
preg_match('/\b\w+\b/i', $sentence, $result);  

// Display result 
echo "The first word of string is: ".$result[0]; 

?>
```

[FIDDLE](https://3v4l.org/ZiLKW)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your code work you just need to add the `u` flag to the regex so that it matches unicode characters:

```
preg_match('/^\w+/iu', $sentence, $result);  
echo "\nThe first word of string is: ".$result[0];
```

Output:

```
The first word of string is: 練馬春日町Ⅳ
```

Note that since you want the first word you can simply anchor your regex with `^` and the second `\b` is not required as `\w+` will match as many word characters as it can i.e. until it gets to the first word break.

Alternatively you can use [`mb_split`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-split) with a regex of [`\p{Z}`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php) which matches any unicode whitespace or invisible separator:

```
$sentence = '練馬春日町Ⅳ　清掃レポート.pdf'; 
$first_word = mb_split('\p{Z}', $sentence);
echo $first_word[0];
```

Output:

```
練馬春日町Ⅳ
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/VFs9M)